# UTF-8 error code/encode string

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, encode

guys. I have a problem. When I get some words in VK dialogs in Russian - server back to me this: (\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88 \xd1\x88\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88). Bad code to me, I need a normal words :(
I tried decode/encode this string, but I got error

```
out=out[-2],out[-11][1:-1]
out=out.decode('utf8')
```

File "C:/Users/Zyzz/Desktop\vkplus.py", line 22, in GetLastMessage
    out=out.decode('utf8')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'.
Help me, pls(

Comment: Obviously tuple can not be decoded, you should index the tuple to get the desired string, then you can decode it.

Comment: what do you try to do in first line ? you create tuple .

Answer (score 0):

*Russian - server back to me this: (…)*. Completely unclear what's that object. Let me guess:

```
back_bytes = b'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88 \xd1\x88\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88'
print(back_bytes, type(back_bytes))
out= back_bytes.decode('utf8')
print(out, type(out), '\n')

back_tuple = b'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88',b'\xd1\x88\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88'
print(back_tuple, type(back_tuple))
out = (d.decode('utf8') for d in back_tuple)
print(list(out), type(out), '\n')

back_list = [b'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88',b'\xd1\x88\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88']
print(back_list, type(back_list))
out = [d.decode('utf8') for d in back_list]
print(out, type(out), '\n')
```

**Output:** `40690447.py`

> ```
> b'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88 \xd1\x88\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88' <class 'bytes'>
> Слыш шыш <class 'str'>
>
> (b'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88', b'\xd1\x88\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88') <class 'tuple'>
> ['Слыш', 'шыш'] <class 'generator'>
>
> [b'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88', b'\xd1\x88\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88'] <class 'list'>
> ['Слыш', 'шыш'] <class 'list'>
> ```